# Avoid showing Null to a razor view engine

Tags: .net, razor, model-view-controller

I'm programming a school information system with a MVC .net application. But I can't seem to be able to avoid showing null in one of my section

I tried an If statement in my controller and also in my view so that it won't show anything other than the people who are graduated
[In this picture I'm showing the page where I want to show only the people with the gratuated status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJBbJ.png)

In controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var graduates = db.Graduated_Students;
    return View(graduates.ToList());
}
```

In model:

```
public partial class Graduated_Students
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CohortId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string ContractStatus { get; set; }
    public string DepositStatus { get; set; }
    public string GraduationStatus { get; set; }
}
```

In view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
     <tr>
         <td>
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
         </td>
         <td>
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName)
         </td>
         <td>
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CohortId)
         </td>
         <td>

         </td>
         <td>

         </td>
         <td>
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GraduationStatus)
         </td>
```

Comment: What, exactly, is null, and what do you consider a “section”?

Comment: @cwharris I've just edited the question, is it clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
var graduates = db.Graduated_Students;
```

To

```
var graduates = db.Graduated_Students.Where(student => student.GraduationStatus != null);
```

Which will filter out all students without a graduation status (because graduation status is null for that student).